# Using $concat with $project is giving error : 'MongoError: $concat only supports strings, not double'?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, mean-stack

I have a mongoose model in which some fields are like :

```
var AssociateSchema = new Schema({
    personalInformation: {
       familyName: { type: String },
       givenName: { type: String }
    }
})
```

I want to perform a '$regex' on the concatenation of familyName and givenName (something like 'familyName + " " + 'givenName'), for this purpose I'm using aggregate framework with $concat inside $project to produce a 'fullName' field and then '$regex' inside $match to search on that field. The code in mongoose for my query is:

```
Associate.aggregate([
    { $project: {fullName: { $concat: [                                  
    'personalInformation.givenName','personalInformation.familyName']}}},
    $match: { fullName: { 'active': true, $regex: param, $options: 'i' } }}
])
```

But it's giving me error:

> MongoError: $concat only supports strings, not double on the first
>   stage of my aggregate pipeline i.e $project stage.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error and then discovered that indeed one of the documents in the collection was to blame. They way I fished it out was by filtering by field type as [explained in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/):

```
db.addressBook.find( { "zipCode" : { $type : "double" } } )
```

I found the field had the value `NaN`, which to my eyes wouldn't be a number, but mongodb interprets it as such.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by using $substr method, so the $project part of my aggregate pipeline is now:

```
`$project: {
                        fullName: {
                            $concat: [
                                { $substr: ['$personalInformation.givenName', 0, -1] }, ' ', { $substr: ['$personalInformation.familyName', 0, -1] }
                            ]
                        }

                    }
                }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I'm not sure why $concat isn't working for you unless you've had some integers sneak into some of your document fields. Have you tried having a $-sign in front of your concatenated values? as in, '$personalInformation.givenName'? Are you sure every single familyName and givenName is a string, not a double, in your collection? All it takes is one double for your $concat to fold.

In any case, I had a similar type mismatch problem with actual doubles. $concat indeed supports only strings, and usually, all you'd do is cast any non-strings to strings.. but alas, at the time of this writing MongoDB 3.6.2 does not yet support integer/double => string casting, only date => string casting. Sad face.

That said, try adding this projection hack at the top of your query. This worked for me as a typecast. Just make sure you provide a long enough byte length (128-byte name is pretty long so you should be okay).

```
{
 $project: {
   castedGivenName: { 
     $substrBytes: [ 'personalInformation.givenName', 0, 128 ] 
   },
   castedFamilyName: {
     $substrBytes: [ 'personalInformation.familyName', 0, 128 ]
   }
},
{ 
 $project: { 
   fullName: { 
     $concat: [                                  
      '$castedGivenName',
      '$castedFamilyName'
     ]
   }
 }
},
{
  $match: { fullName: { 'active': true, $regex: param, $options: 'i' } }
}
```